# Does locality emerge from (classical) Lagrangian mechanics?

Tags: classical-mechanics, special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism

Consider a (classical) system of several interacting particles.  Can it be shown that, if the Lagrangian of such a system is Lorenz invariant, there cannot be any space-like influences between the particles?

Comment: Suggestion for the title(v2): _Classically, does locality emerge from a Lorentz-invariant action?_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A counterexample:

1) Take two particles in a laboratory S

2) Set the clocks attached to the particles so that at laboratory time $t=0$ both clocks show $\tau_1=0$, $\tau_2=0$

3) Leave the particles to evolve under the following lorentz-invariant lagrangian:

$$
\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{L}_1+\mathcal{L}_2+\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{int}}\\
\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{int}}=u^{~\mu}_1(\tau_1)u_{2\mu}(\tau_2),
$$
where $\mathcal{L}_1,\mathcal{L}_2$ are free-particle lagrangians. The total lagrangian is lorenz-invariant, but the physical system is not due to its initial setup, which allows the lagrangian to transmit the interactions in a space-like manner.

Answer (score 2):

Lorentz covariance is not enough as there are superluminal representations of the Poincare group, featuring tachyons. (See the section ''What about particles faster than light (tachyons)?'' in Chapter A7: Time and space of my 
[theoretical physics FAQ](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~neum/physfaq/physics-faq.html) for some background on tachyons)

The condition required for causality beyond Lorentz invariance is that the resulting system of differential equations is symmetric hyperbolic.